# $\displaystyle\Big(1-\frac{t}{n}\Big)^n$ is strictly increasing for $n>N$ and $t>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that $\exists N\in\mathbb N$ such that, $\displaystyle\Big(1-\frac{t}{n}\Big)^n$ is strictly increasing for $n>N$
>
> $(n\in\mathbb N, t>0)$

Bernoulli Inequality didn't help me

I did;

$\displaystyle\frac{\Big(1-\frac{t}{n+1}\Big)^{n+1}}{\Big(1-\frac{t}{n}\Big)^n}=\Big(1+\frac{t}{(n+1)(n-t)}\Big)^n\Big(1-\frac{t}{n+1}\Big)$

$\displaystyle\Big(1+\frac{t}{(n+1)(n-t)}\Big)^n\ge\Big(1+\frac{nt}{(n+1)(n-t)}\Big)$$\quad$Bernoulli-Ineq.

but

$\displaystyle\Big(1+\frac{nt}{(n+1)(n-t)}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{t}{n+1}\Big)=1+\underbrace{\frac{nt}{(n+1)(n-t)}-\frac{t}{n+1}-\frac{nt^2}{(n+1)^2(n-t)}}_{\text{doesn't seem to be positive}}$

So it didn't work, do you have any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try differentiating with respect to $n$?  The formula does make sense when $n$ is real, not necessarily an integer, and if it is increasing over the reals, then it is also increasing over the integers.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Sorry $n\in\mathbb N$

Comment: Yes, but like I said, if it is increasing as a function of the reals, then it is necessarily increasing over the integers.

Comment: @Stephen Montgomery-Smith Did you mean $n\frac{t}{n^2}(1-\frac{t}{n})^{n-1}<1$ ?

Comment: No.  I meant to differentiate with respect to $n$, not $t$.  (But I think you have an error in your formula even if it is meant to be the derivative with respect to $t$.)

Comment: @Stephen Montgomery-Smith Finally I got it $(1-\frac{t}{n})^n[\ln(1-\frac{t}{n})-\frac{t}{t-n}]$

Comment: I would suggest writing out the first few terms of Taylor's series for $\log$, and see if you get something provably positive.

Comment: But also, Bernoulli's inequality came from the first two terms of the binomial expansion.  You could see what you get from the first three or more terms of the binomial expansion.  And I think it would be equivalent to the proof I suggested above.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith So the statement is wrong, but is then the negation correct ?

Comment: The statement is correct.  Using an extra term in the binomial expansion seems to work.  My idea of using Taylor series for $\log$ is probably harder than your suggested approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as $n\gt t$, apply Bernoulli:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(1-\frac t{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1-\frac tn\right)^n}
&=\left(1+\frac t{(n+1)(n-t)}\right)^{n+1}\left(1-\frac tn\right)\\
&\ge\left(1+\frac t{n-t}\right)\left(1-\frac tn\right)\\[9pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Awesome, and the inequality is strict for $n\ge 2$

Comment: @derivative: Since the exponent is $n+1$, the inequality should be strict for $n\ge1$, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry it seems too late, but the accepted answer isn't based on OP's work, and it doesn't address OP's doubt on his/her expansion.

In fact, you're on the right track.  Just continue your calculations, and the sum of the last three terms in your expansion will turn out to be positive.

Assume that $n > t$, so that the factors in the denominator is positive.

\begin{align}
&\quad \frac{nt}{(n+1)(n-t)}-\frac{t}{n+1}-\frac{nt^2}{(n+1)^2(n-t)} \\
&= \frac{nt(n+1) - t(n+1)(n-t) - nt^2}{(n+1)^2(n-t)} \tag{*} \label{sp} \\
&= \frac{nt(n+1) - nt(n+1) + t^2(n+1) - nt^2}{(n+1)^2(n-t)} \\
&= \frac{nt^2 + t^2 - nt^2}{(n+1)^2(n-t)} \\
&= \frac{t^2}{(n+1)^2(n-t)} > 0
\end{align}

In $\eqref{sp}$ we split the middle term $- t(n+1)(n-t)$ into two terms.  In the last line, we have a strict inequality because it's given that $t > 0$ and we have assumed that $n > t$.